# Custom CollectionViewCell handling button press

Tags: swift, ios8, uicollectionview, cell, uicollectionviewcell

In my app I have a custom collectionViewCell. Let's call it customCell. This customCell contains one titleLabel, one imageView and two buttons. Let's call it tlLbl, imgView, btn1 and btn2.

**Goal:** If I click one of the buttons I would like to present a new viewController. This new viewController should get tlLbl and the imgView as parameter. I need both because I'll show the label and the image in the new viewController, too.

**Consideration:** The cleanest solution would be to present the new viewController in the customCell class. Passing the parameters wouldn't be a problem here. But it is not possible to change views in customCell classes.

Ok, it doesn't matter. Next solution. I can handle the button pressed actions in my current viewController. Adding a GestureRecognizer in the collectionView delegate function "cellForItemAtIndexPath" for btn1 and btn2 should solve this problem. Oh no, it doesn't solve the problem. My current code:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
   let customCell:customCellClass = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("customCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as customCellClass

   customCell.tlLbl.text="Test1"
   customCell.imgView.image=UIImage(named: "myImg.png")

   var tapRec = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "btnTapped")
   var tapRec2 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "btnTapped2")

   customCell.btn1.addGestureRecognizer(tapRec)
   customCell.btn2.addGestureRecognizer(tapRec2)

   return customCell
}

//Btn tapped handler
func btnTapped() {
   let vc = newViewController() //change this to your class name
   self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func btnTapped2() {
   let vc = newViewController2() //change this to your class name
   self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**Question:** How can I pass tlLbl and imgView from customCell to the new viewController after tapping a button in customCell. The action parameter in UITapGestureRecognizer

```
var tapRec = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "btnTapped")
```

doesn't allow to pass your own parameters.

I need help. Puh ...

Comment: Can you please share code of UICollectionViewDataSource? It will help to resolve this issue. - Dipak

Comment: The datasource is shared already? Do dou mean the "cellForItemAtIndexPath" function?

Comment: numberOfItemsInSection and numberOfSectionsInCollectionView

Comment: get solved this issue. I have to write my own protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I only use the numberOfItemsInSection method. It returns a count of jsonFiles.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
  return jsonParsedArr.count
}
```

jsonParsedArr is an Array with json content.

For the customCell I created a nib file registered in "viewDidLoad".